# What does span {} do in CSS syntax?

Tags: css, formatting

I got some example CSS code (well written and working) with many **span** statements inside, that I modified for my use.  What exactly they do?  VS Code shows me as an error, but browsers don't complain, and I couldn't find any references in the CSS documentation, as if this syntax does not exist.
Example:

```
h2 {
  letter-spacing: 2vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 8vw;
    letter-spacing: -1vw;
  }
}
```

VS code complains:

```
"code": "css-colonexpected",
"severity": 8,
"message": "colon expected",
"source": "css",
```

If I add colon it would be suggesting keys right away, and would not accept anything in curly brackets{}
Thanks

Comment: you are trying to use less/scss/sass syntax instead of css, so just change your css complier to use less/etc... also my answer would explain the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the brackets `{` and `}` define scope so that

```css
   body {
       color: #000;
   }
```

Would define that the `color` (text color) of the `body` element type (css query selector) would be `#000` (which is hex for black)

however, if you have an element in an element like this using `a precompiler` such as [less](https://lesscss.org/) for `css` using the `less` syntax.

```
    body {
        color: #000;
        span {
            color: #FF0000;
        }
    }
```

this would do as the previous `css` did, but in `less` you can create a hierarchy

the body's color will be set to black as before.
and then any span child of the body element will have its color set to red (#FF0000)

CSS/LESS are used in conjunction with the HTML DOM object model.

Comment: Thanks @Dean Van Greunen, for the explanation it makes perfect sense.  However when I try it it doesn't work ie:  scss file I put: `h2 { color: black; span { color: red; }}`  and I tried in my html code: `<h2> Black text </h2><h2> <span> Should be red</span></h2>`  I also tried to use `span class=h2` but no luck.  Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that this syntax doesn't exist for CSS, as it doesn't support nested selectors like this.

The correct syntax would be:

```
h2 {
  letter-spacing: 2vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 8vw;
  letter-spacing: -1vw;
}
```

This syntax is of course perfectly acceptable if you use a [CSS preprocessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_preprocessor), like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](https://lesscss.org/) for example. CSS preprocessors compile CSS written like you've done into standard CSS syntax, and add extra functionality, like using variables and conditional statements.

I think that modern browsers are probably capable of understanding syntax like this in certain situations, but if you want to use to this sort of syntax then using a preprocessor is a safer option to avoid errors.

Comment: Thanks @dave. What do you mean preprocessor?  An add-in in VS Code for syntax highlight/debug or server side preprocessor to interpret html/css

Comment: CSS preprocessors run on the client (on your machine) as part of your development workflow. A tool like SASS for instance listens for changes in the non-standard CSS you're writing, and compiles in real time what you've written into standard CSS.

Comment: Yes, I see, I renamed .css to .scss and now no more errors, and added plugin for scss intellisense.

Comment: VSCode has support for preprocessors like SASS and LESS to check your syntax, but you'll need to install them on your machine as a task runner to 'watch' what you're writing. Have a look at the SASS guide: https://sass-lang.com/guide